# setRepeating won't cancel from other activity

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I see there is a lot of similar questions but I have my alarm info stored in a database. The reminder is cancelled inside the database by a call to deleteReminder and it looks like this

```
 public boolean deleteReminder(long rowId) {

    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;


}
```

This deletes the reminder but not the alarm.  I tried changing it to

```
public boolean deleteReminder(long rowId) {

    new ReminderManager(this).cancelReminder();


    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;

}
```

and added a cancelReminder method in my ReminderManager activity like this

public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when, String spinInterval) {
        Log.e(TAG, spinInterval);

```
    long l = Long.parseLong(spinInterval);



    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId); 

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 

    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), l, pi);
}

public void cancelReminder(){

      Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
      PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

      mAlarmManager.cancel(pi);

     }
```

but it didn't work....    Can you show me the correct code to make the alarm stop repeating?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but you are using `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` instead of `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` for the cancel `PendingIntent`. Have you tried making both `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`?

Comment: Cool. I'll put it in an answer so you can mark it for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` for both calls to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. The code you posted uses `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` the second time you call it.